# Trait which returns iterator with lifetime bounded by the lifetime of an argument

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime

I have a trait which says that any implementation of `Foo` needs to provide a method `bar` which returns an object of some type which implements `Iterator<Item = u32>`:

```
trait Foo {
    type FooIterator: Iterator<Item = u32>;
    fn bar(&self) -> FooIterator;
}
```

For this case, I believe that the default lifetime elision means that the iterator returned by `bar` is required to live on its own, without being tied to the lifetime of the `Foo` it is iterating over.  User Habnabit on #rust irc suggested the following way to say that the lifetime of the `FooIterator` is less than the lifetime of the `Foo`. i.e. it allows the implementation of the `FooIterator` to keep a reference to the `Foo` that it comes from:

```
trait Foo<'a> {
    type FooIterator: Iterator<Item = u32> + 'a;
    fn bar<'b: 'a>(&'b self) -> Self::FooIterator;
}
```

What I really want is the case where the function `bar` takes an additional argument, and the implementation of `FooIterator` is allowed to keep a reference to both the `Foo` and the additional argument. i.e. the lifetime of `FooIterator` is bounded by the lifetime of the `Foo` and the lifetime of the additional argument.

My literal translation of this idea would be

```
trait Zip {}
trait Foo<'a, 'c> {
    type FooIterator: Iterator<Item = u32> + 'a + 'c;
    // Foo.bar() returns an iterator that has a lifetime less than the Foo
    fn bar<'b: 'a, 'd: 'c>(&'b self, &'d Zip) -> Self::FooIterator;
}
```

But I was told there there is no "good" way to do this.  What would be the best way to implement this idiom?  What would the above code do exactly?

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is [associated type constructors](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2016/11/02/associated-type-constructors-part-1-basic-concepts-and-introduction/), a planned feature that is not yet implemented in Rust. With associated type constructors, your code would look like this:

```
trait Zip {}
trait Foo {
    type FooIterator<'a, 'c>: Iterator<Item = u32> + 'a + 'c;
    // Foo.bar() returns an iterator that has a lifetime less than the Foo
    fn bar<'a, 'b: 'a, 'c, 'd: 'c>(&'b self, &'d Zip) -> Self::FooIterator<'a, 'c>;
}
```

Actually, I'm not sure all those lifetimes are necessary, because a `&'a T` can be coerced to a `&'b T` where `'a: 'b`. Thus, the following might be good enough:

```
trait Zip {}
trait Foo {
    type FooIterator<'a, 'c>: Iterator<Item = u32> + 'a + 'c;
    // Foo.bar() returns an iterator that has a lifetime less than the Foo
    fn bar<'a, 'c>(&'a self, &'c Zip) -> Self::FooIterator<'a, 'c>;
}
```

Comment: You must have an alert every time I ask a Rust question :) Interesting, but it doesn't seem like associated type constructors are going to be in Rust any time soon.  What would the workaround be?

Comment: I'm watching https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust, and I'm not alone. ;) As far as I know, there's no workaround, which is why this feature is in the process of being developed.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you want to use this trait, you may be able to make it work by implementing it for `&'a Struct` instead of for `Struct`, thus "hoisting" the responsibility for finding the right lifetime from the trait into the caller.

Remove the lifetime annotation from the trait and change `bar` so it takes `self`, plus another argument of the same lifetime:

```
trait Foo {
    type FooIterator: Iterator<Item = u32>;
    fn bar(self, other: Self) -> Self::FooIterator;
}
```

(Removing `'a` from the trait is possible because `bar` consumes the reference instead of reborrowing it -- `self` doesn't have to outlive the return value anymore because it's been moved into it.)

Then `impl` it for a reference of lifetime `'a`:

```
impl<'a> Foo for &'a Vec<u32> {
    type FooIterator = ...; // something presumably containing 'a
    fn bar(self, other: Self) -> Self::FooIterator {
        ...
    }
}
```

This works because the compiler can limit the lifetime `'a` to one for which the impl applies.

[Here's a playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=14c0ec2549a35f87b06fe3d2d6f7abb8&version=stable&backtrace=0) where `bar` is basically a wrapper around `.chain()`.

I'm ignoring the `Zip` trait for now because how to incorporate it depends on what it provides. Instead, I suppose that `bar` only accepts an argument of the same type as `Self`. However, you can probably add it as well, maybe using the same technique if you need to.